# Windows service & mutilthreading

Tags: multithreading, windows-services, execution

I have a windows service, which is executed regular intervals... Here is the code snippet:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    tickTack = new Timer(10000);
    tickTack.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(tickTack_Elapsed);
    tickTack.Start();
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    tickTack.Stop();
}
private void tickTack_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    objProc = new Processing();
    objProc.start();
}
```

In my `start()` method of Processing Class do my actual work like below.

```
public void start()
{
    try
    {
        Process_Requests();
        Process_Exports();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorLogs.SaveError(ex, "");
    }
}
```

How does the execution is happen when the execution done in a single thread??? For example, the first method takes time for execution then what about second method????

Now I want to call `Process_request()` and `Preocess_export()` methods. Each method should connect to multiple databases. In this situation, would I need to create new thread for each connection and do my work... I am not sure.

```
public void start()
{
    try
    {
        #region 
        sqlConObjects = new List<SqlConnection>();

        // Here i am getting multiple connection strings 
        List<string> conStrings = GetConnectionStrings(); 
        foreach (string strCon in conStrings)
        {
            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(strCon);
            sqlConObjects.Add(sqlCon);
        }

        foreach (SqlConnection sqlCon in sqlConObjects)
        {
            //sqlCon.Open();
            Thread t = new Thread(ProcessRequest);
            t.Start((object)sqlCon);

            Thread t1=new Thread(ProcessExports);
            t1.Start((object)sqlCon);
        }
        #endregion  
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorLogs.SaveError(ex, "");
    }
}
```

Can anyone please explain how to do this... is thread is created or no need??? How should the execution is happen if we are not creating a thread for each connection object.

Answer (score 0):

Timer works on ThreadPool
From MSDN
The callback method executed by the timer should be reentrant, because it is called on ThreadPool threads. The callback can be executed simultaneously on two thread pool threads if the timer interval is less than the time required to execute the callback, or if all thread pool threads are in use and the callback is queued multiple times.

Also in your's code you don't keep reference to timer object and it will be collected.

As for me you should use ThreadPool. Createing a lot of threads is bad practice